# recently switched from PHP to Rails Passenger. Can't make index.php redirect to /

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Rails 3 on phusion passenger with apache
on development server in routes.rb

```
match "/index.php" => redirect("/")
```

works fine. In production it throws a 404 and its an Apache 404 page not a Rails 404 page
Took out  DirectoryIndex from httpd.conf and .htaccess.
If you make a redirect like /sub/index.php it works fine just not in the root.

Anyone know what the problem could be or how to work around? I am afraid people have bookmarked index.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting, does it work if you just point index.php straight at the root controller/action?

```
match "/index.php" => "welcome#index"
```

Comment: I get the same resulting 404 with that method. :(